Ant design vue autocomplete with input-number custom input
I want to have a number input as autocomplete custom input for ant-design-vue like so
<a-auto-complete
  v-model:value="form.discount"
  :options="discountAutoComplete(form.discount)"
>
  <a-input-number placeholder="discount..." />
</a-auto-complete>

But I keep getting this error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')
    at onInputChange (index.js:139:11)
    at onChange (SingleSelector.js:145:11)
    at Proxy.onInput (Input.js:144:11)
    at collectInputValue (InputNumber.js:272:68)
    at onInternalInput (InputNumber.js:295:7)
    at callWithErrorHandling (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:195:19)
    at callWithAsyncErrorHandling (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:202:17)
    at HTMLInputElement.invoker (runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js:693:5)

This mainly because input-number change outputs the value(number or string) and the other regular inputs change event outputs an event object and the autocomplete expects an event object, is there a workaround for this, is there some sort of config I can use to make this work?
